# Is there a way to refresh filter data on slider input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a dataset containing product models, and I want to make a filter that filters through them with a range slider. My dataset gets reduced to 0, when I want it to refresh on slider input.

Here's a breakdown: I have data like this:

```
const stratPickups = {
    "Model 1": {
        name: "Clean Model",
        design: "Single Coil",
        output: 4,
        look: "traditional"
    },
    "Model 2": {
        name: "Balanced Model",
        design: "Single Coil",
        output: 5,
        look: "traditional"
    },
    "Model 3": {
        name: "Balanced Model 2",
        design: "Single Coil",
        output: 6,
        look: "traditional"
    },
    "Model 4": {
        name: "High Output Model",
        design: "Single Coil",
        output: 8,
        look: "traditional"
    },
}
```

I also have a change event that loads the data like this:

```
if (e.target.value === "strat") {
      data = Object.values(stratPickups);
      refreshView();
```

Which calls a function `refreshView()` which populates the screen with "cards" like so:

```
const refreshView = () => {
    output.innerHTML = "";
    data.forEach((p) => {
      output.innerHTML += `
    
    <div class="card pickup-result" data-output="${p.output}" data-tone="${p.tone}">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-heading">
      <h4>${p.name}</h4>
      <a class="link-button" target="blank" href="${p.url}">See Product</a>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <h5>Specs:</h5>
      <p><strong>Output: </strong> ${p.output}</p>
      <p><strong>Description:</strong> ${p.description}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    `;
    });
  };
```

Lastly, I have a slider that filters by the output. The goal is to slide and match the slider value to the output, and call `refreshView()` when there's a match, like so:

```
const sliderFunction() {

    let sliderValue = Math.floor(slider.value / 10);
    data = Object.values(data);
    data = data.filter((p) => p.output === sliderValue);

    refreshView();
}
```

**Problem:**
The above works, but it reduces my data to 0 as it filters out the results that do not match. Is there a way to "refresh" the data back to its normal state so the original dataset remains intact?

**Codepen**
If you want to play with it, here's a codepen. Instructions: select "Stratocaster pickups" from second dropdown to load stratocaster pickups data,

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/mdVaoqe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to mutate the `data` variable. `data` is a state used across the code. If it's changed, during slider change, `data`'s values need to be restored to the full list.

Alternatively, do not mutate the global state variable `data`. Create another variable called `filteredData` which can be a transient state and use it in the `refreshView`.

Comment: So, I'm confused on how to use a variable `filteredData` in `refreshView()`. Since `refreshView()` takes in the `data` variable to build the cards. How would you approach this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, I got it! I changed the  function to `refreshView(dataSet)` to pass in a data set. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you pass `filteredData` as a parameter to `refreshView()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Have two variable to store the selected value in dropdown and slider. Wherever you are filtering take these two variable's value into consideration.